# Single Calendar control with multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a GridView with multiple date columns in it.
For dates, I use textboxes. I would like to use ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender to make inserting dates easier. But if I place a ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender in each ItemTemplate, it will make my page much slower. Could you please tell me how I can use one ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender for all textboxes? I guess, the calendar should appear when the user clicks a textbox. And of course, the calendar should appear somewhere next to the textbox.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't thing there's a way or a easy way to do it. You could think to use another component. Have you known datapicker from jquery ui ? It's nice, free, clean and fast calendar component. Using it, you can apply a css style in your textboxes and filter it by jquery doing a calendar, using datepicker, something like this:

your textboxes inside the gridview:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" CssClass="date" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate2" runat="server" CssClass="date" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate3" runat="server" CssClass="date" />
```

and in bottom of your webform, you could do a jquery script

```
<script language='javascript'>
   $(function() { // <- page_load in client side with jQuery
      // get all inputs that has .date css style and apply datepicker
      $("input.date").datepicker(); 
   });
</script>
```

Read more about jquery ui to know how to setup it on your application (basically, add a javascript file and css file)

---

Take a look at these links:

http://www.jquery.com
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

PS: Sorry for my english!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I have my controls in a user control, can I put the script you gave in master page? Or it should go in each ascx where I use the calendar? And where can I get the css for "date"? Also, does your solution have anything to do with plug-in that Ethem Kuloglu mentioned?

Comment: IE gives me error: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; IE0006_ver1;EN_US)
Timestamp: Tue, 19 Jul 2011 20:13:37 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 16630

Comment: Well... you should have this script one time in your page. The css for date is only to jquery knows about the fields with this style will be apply the datepicker component. It's the same plugin that Enthem mentioned. The thing is, you need to add jquery reference (get this javascript in jquery.com), and after you need to add jquery ui reference (ui.jquery.com). jQuery is necessary to Jquery UI works.

Comment: I added  <link type="text/css" href="CSS/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
and  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
at the beginning of my master page, and I have this within the master page body:       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="date"></asp:TextBox>
 and at the end of the master page, I have this: </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { jQuery                   $("input.date").datepicker();
        }); 
    </script> When I click the textbox, nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the jquery you're using is old. Don't you  include de .js file for jquery ui? You need: jquery js file, jquery ui js file, jquery ui css file. Take a look at this link I've just do http://jsbin.com/enozam/edit, I preffer to keep my scripts before the </body> tag. You can keep it on your webform (not necessary in masterpage).

Comment: Thanks Felipe, not it worked. I have one more question. The calendar has no arrows to go to the next or previous month. There are buttons for it, but they are invisible until you place the mouse over them. Is it possible to change it somehow to have visible arrows or buttons? Also, why is it better to keep the script before the </body> tag? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, in the previous comment I made a typo. I meant "Now it worked". It's not clear to me how to format date to display 2-digit year.

Comment: I don't understand why the datepicker in your example has arrows, and mine doesn't have, though I just copied your code...

Comment: OK, I fugured out how to do formatting, but not the Prev and Next arrows.

Comment: hi, jQuery UI has some images that are setted in .css file. You should check if the path of these images can be see for .css file. Otherwise you can see the documentation of this components and other of jquery ui in http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: @Felipe let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1666/discussion-between-dpreznik-and-felipe)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you yo use jQuery plug-in. Visit http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

this plug-in helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me a little example how to use it? Thanks.